# Spring 4 SPEL null injection

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have a spring bean in which I want to optional.

I tried something like this:

```
    <bean id="springSqlSessionConfigBasedFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="infraDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="#{ (!''.eqauls(${myBatis.configLocation})) ? ${myBatis.configLocation} : 'null' }" />
</bean>
```

so - if the property (loaded by properties configurer) exists it should inject that value and if not it should inject a null.

I get this exception running the above:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.<init>(SpelNodeImpl.java:54)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.<init>(Ternary.java:36)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:136)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:85)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:56)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:32)
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpressions(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:154)
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseTemplate(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:85)
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:73)
at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:123)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but in your code there is `eqauls` instead of `equals`. Does changing it help?

Comment: embarrassing as my typo may be - that's not the reason. same error.

Comment: I tried to recreate your code in a simple project and what I needed to do to get it working was to quote the property placeholders like so: `<property name="configLocation" value="#{ (!''.equals('${myBatis.configLocation}')) ? '${myBatis.configLocation}' : 'null' }" />`. But if I didn't I got a different Exception than the one in your answer so that probably won't be it either

Comment: Thanks for trying. Your change has basically removed the reference to an external property.

Comment: @bohuslav-burghardt was close; see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by by @bohuslav-burghardt, you need to quote the placeholders.

However, you must **not** quote the null...

```
value="#{!''.equals('${foo}') ? '${foo}' : null}"
```

...worked fine for me.

EDIT:

To answer the question in the comment below, you need to set `ignore-unresolvable` to `true` on the placeholder configurer and test for an unresolved placeholder:

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.amqp.Foo">
  <property name="foo"
   value="#{(!''.equals('${foo}') AND !'${foo}'.contains('{foo}')) ? '${foo}' : null}" />
</bean>
```

Notice that it uses `contains` and omits the `$` in order to avoid that argument being replaced; otherwise, a good replacement will fail that test and cause null to be injected.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for this to work even if 'foo' parameter doesn't exist at all (and not only if it is empty)?